# Joomla Site Meta Hack

Tags: html, security, joomla, keyword, code-injection

My clients joomla site has suffered a strange hack and I cant quite put my finger down on how its even working?

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bishamabbeysailing.co.uk+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=XbT&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=+site:bishamabbeysailing.co.uk+bishamabbeysailing.co.uk&sa=X&ei=zL5SUdauNMnWOffggJgC&ved=0CE4QrAM&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44342787,d.ZWU&fp=c50a33b4a78ecaf3&biw=1920&bih=909

> Meta Description Google - 
>   Cuts for any probeer! Amoksiklav 1000 mg sandoz: While the...

If you see the results all the pages have drug related meta descriptions and keywords but when you visit the website everything looks fine.

http://www.bishamabbeysailing.co.uk/

> Meta Description Website -  "Bisham Abbey Sailing & Navigation School, RYA boat handling courses....

Comment: Probably either cached data from before something was fixed or user agent sniffing. We can't see see your code though.

Comment: The template file looks fine and so do the index, im rather baffled how they did this.

Comment: @BrentFrench, that is because [it is only reacting to specific user-agents](http://pastebin.com/aTebcbXK). As you can see, it is reacting to at least two major crawlers. You may need to look further than the normal web browser's templates

Comment: Like Alexander wrote, you need to get a security specialist checking your host. It's likely the webserver has been tainted. Likely Apache.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may be most likely in the main index.php or in the template. Or it may be even in the .htaccess file.

The hack for sure is checking for the user-agent as Alexander said. So you can do a search for it and see if that finds anything in your files. Also check for files which shouldn't be there in a normal installation.

If you're not familiar with the Joomla filestructure, the best bet is to delete everything and set it up clean again. Or use a professional service like myjoomla.com perform an audit for you or even clean it for you.

Comment: I develop for Joomla so i'm quite sure with how things work but I guess I will roll back to a older version.

Comment: I'l tick you up for the answer anyway :)

Comment: Did you check the .htaccess file? A backup does not necessary include this one.

Comment: This is not an answer. Especially as currently there are many high-profile hacks of the webservers (and not the PHP sites underneath), this "answer" suggests even wrong. Leave such low-level-assumptions to comments please.